# f(x)g(x) is not an indeterminate form?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity, indeterminate-forms

Why is it that when $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$  and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ , $g(x)f(x)$ is not an indeterminate form?

Comment: You have certain problems when you have $\infty\cdot0$ because we want any real number being multiplied by $0$ to map to $0$ always. However, $\infty$ is something we want to have keep going forever. So what happens with $0\cdot\infty$? Which one wins? The reason $1\cdot\infty$ is not indeterminate is because the $1$ only scales the limit, meaning it will still "go on forever".

Answer (score 4):

Rigorous proof :

Let $C$ be an arbitary positive real number.
For sufficient large $x$ we have $$f(x)\ge 0.99$$ and $$g(x)\ge C$$

Hence $$f(x)g(x)\ge 0.99\cdot C$$

Since $C$ was arbitary, the limit must be $\infty$